# Do angels come in the divine category?

Tags: angels, divine-characteristics

Are angels considered divine for being heavenly beings? Was the adjective divine θεῖος /θείας *theios* ever used for angels? Whether in Greek scripture OT NT, early Christians or in Hebrew Bible? What is the general view on this from Christian or Heb commentators? Since, the same word has been used for sulphur, I suspect could be used for the heavenly beings as well. The question is originally focused on linguistic classification of angels as *divine*, however, I am forced to make it broader to avoid close objections.

> Thayer Lexicon: θεῖον, θείου, τό (apparently the neuter of the adjective θεῖος equivalent to divine incense, because burning brimstone was regarded as having power to purify, and to ward off contagion (but Curtius, sec. 320 allies it with θύω; cf. Latin fumus, English dust)), brimstone: Luk 17:29; Rev 9:17f; Rev 14:10; Rev 19:20; (Rev 20:10); Rev 21:8. (Gen 19:24; Ps 10:6 (Ps 11:6); Ezek 38:22; Homer, Iliad 16, 228; Odyssey 22, 481, 493; (Plato) Tim. Locr., p. 99 c.; Aelian v. h. 13, 15 (16); Herodian, 8, 4, 26 (9 edition, Bekker).)*

and for *lightening* by Homer.

> LSJ: θεῖον (A), Ep. θέειον (in Od. 22.493 θήϊον ), τό , brimstone , used to fumigate and purify, δέπας . . ἐκάθηρε θεείῳ Il. 16.228 ; οἶσε θέειον . . , κακῶν ἄκος Od. 22.481 ; δεινὴ δὲ θεείου γίγνεται ὀδμή , from a thunderbolt, Il. 14.415 ; ἐν δὲ θεείου πλῆτο , of a ship struck by lightning, Od. 12.417 ; ἐμβαλόντες πῦρ ξὺν θ . Th. 2.77 , cf. 4.100 ; Κύριος ἔβρεξεν ἐπὶ Σόδομα καὶ Γόμορρα θ. καὶ πῦρ LXX Ge. 19.24 ; as a natural product, Hp. Aër. 7, Ph. 2.21 , 143 , Ti.Locr. 99c ; θ. ἄπυρον Gal. 12.903 ; opp. πεπυρωμένον , Dsc. 5.107; cf. θεάφιον, θέαφος . (Perh. cogn. with θύω, θυμιάω , Lat. suffire.)

Comment: The word _theios_ is used twice in holy scripture, in 1 Peter 1:3 and 1 Peter 1:4. Both times it is specifically related to _Theos_ - to God himself.

Comment: @NigelJ Jesus called the Pharisees rejecting Him divine beings. "Jesus answered them, 'Is it not written in your Law, "I have said you are 'gods'"?'" (John 10:34)

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding of the teachings of Michael Heiser, he would say yes. I remember a podcast of his that I watched where he explained the Hebrew word 'elohim' (which we English-speakers tend to translate as 'God') is a word that describes a being's location as outside of the physical world and not a description of that being's nature. Therefore, angels are elohim as is God, but that God is not an angel. The angels were members of God's divine council. See Naked Bible Podcast website.